# Graph API: all comments page has been mentioned in

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to access all the comments where a page has been mentioned in (using @*pagename*)?

I tried using `{page-id}/tagged` but that only gives me messages that were left on the page itself and not the ones the page has been mentioned in a status or comment on a status.

Thanks in advance